# Why not interpreted code can affect "messages" behavior in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a validator in ActiveRecord model, in which I faced with some ***realy strange*** behavior.

Example:

```
if status_changed?
  p status # output on line below
  # <= "my_status_1"
  p my_conditions_1 # output on line below
  # <= false

  if my_conditions_1
    errors.add(:status, 'Error1')
    status = status_was
  end

  p status # output on line below
  # <= nil

  # my_conditions_2 depends on "status variable"
  if my_conditions_2
    errors.add(:status, 'Error2')
    status = 2
  end
end
```

Second condition always failed, because `status` somehow was setted to nil. **But** when I changed `status` to `self.status` everything started working as expected.

**UPDATED**

*I've got the rule, that in case of  assigning attribute I have to use `self`, thanks everyone who explained it. But part of the code's behavior still doesn't obvious to me*

More general example:

```
class Detector
  def status
    "Everything ok"
  end

  def check
    p status
    # <= "Everything ok"
    if false
      status = "Danger!"
    end

    p status
    # <= nil
  end
end

detector = Detector.new
detector.check
```

Can someone explain it? How not interpreted code can *"redirect"* message from method to a variable? Is it ok?

Comment: You only assign something to `status` if `my_conditions_1` is truthy. So, what happens if `my_conditions_1` is falsey? Well, `status` is un-initialized, und un-initialized local variables evaluate to `nil`, just like instance variables.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So how it's prints out correctly before first assignment?

Comment: Because it doesn't exist before the first assignment, and thus is interpreted as a method call, and presumably that method returns some value.

Comment: @JörgWMittag so when it(local variable) appears? I thought, that code in the condition block is ignored when condition `false`

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored"? It isn't executed, but it still has to parsed.

Comment: @JörgWMittag And initialize the variable? Code, that doesn't executed initialize the variable? Isn't it strange?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124351/discussion-between-jorg-w-mittag-and-alexey-suslyakov).

Comment: I've edited my answer, see it it clarifies it at least a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access object's attribute it's fine to do it with `attribute`.

While updating this attribute one should be using `self.attribute`, because otherwise how should Rails know you mean to set its attribute, not define local variable?

Rule of thumb: use `self` for assigning attribute, don't use it for reading the attribute.

## EDIT

Regarding your update:

As **@Jörg W Mittag** said (who would say better?):

> Well, `status` is un-initialized, und un-initialized local variables
>   evaluate to `nil`, just like instance variables.

To make your code sample behave as you expect you would want to call `status` as a method. Look:

```
class Detector
  def status
    "Everything ok"
  end

  def check
    p status
    # <= "Everything ok"

    status = "Danger!" if false

    status() # or method(:status).call
    # <= "Everything ok"
  end
end
```

First `p status` works because Ruby looks for local variable `status`. When it does not find it, it looks for a method called `status` (by method lookup). So it prints it `"Everything ok"`.

Then in parses the `if` statement and sees, that there's *un-initialized* local variable `status`. Thus, when you reference it, it is legitimately `nil`.

So in other words, ***make Ruby know exactly***, what you mean.

Comment: Nah, you actually only need `self` for assignment. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my grammar is lame today, thx for edit! I meant assignment, indeed you can use `destroy`, `update` etc without explicit `self`.

Comment: Or to access a method with the same name as a local variable.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely right way to tell interpreter what exactly do you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating the attribute then you must use `self`

```
self.status = 'something'
```

otherwise rails will assume status as a local variable so

```
puts self.status
#=> "something"

status = 'abc'

puts self.status 
#=> "something"

self.status = 'something else'
puts self.status 
#=> "something else"
```

But you can access the attribute with just `status`.

> why `status` was set to nil?

Maybe because of this line

```
status = status_was
```

before status_changed? maybe the `self.status` was `nil`

Comment: There are no local variables. 
You're right, but your answer doesn't explain why before **failed** condition `status` was right and after it's getting  lost.

Comment: And again you didn't answer my question. Ok, I got it, `status` was local variable, but why it was setted to `nil`?

Comment: @AlexeySuslyakov: we can't say because we don't see the full code. But the source of the problem is identified correctly: you were setting local variable `status` instead of your accessor `status`.

Comment: @AlexeySuslyakov: after glancing through your code again, an obvious solution appears: because `status_was` is nil. Did you debug-print that one?

Comment: @Deepak first condition failed, so it doesn't has to be setted. Whatever, I've  got the rule, thank you